# How to print items from an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have created an ArrayList from an Array. I want to print one random item from this ArrayList.

How do I do this? I have inserted the code.

```
public class Song {

    final String [] songArray = {
        "song1", 
        "song2"
    };

    ArrayList<String> songList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(songArray));

}
```

Comment: `songList.get(new Random().nextInt(songList.size()))`

Comment: You probably meant to do: `List<String> songList = Arrays.asList(songArray);` your code is currently creating *two* lists, the first with `Arrays.asList(songArray)` and then it creates a second one which copies the items from the first one with: `new ArrayList<>(...)`

Comment: @alfasin That won't compile so I doubt that that's what he meant. Now after you changed it, it will compile but there are still many legitimate reasons to create a new list with `new ArrayList<>`. `Arrays.asList` is a very cheap operation which servers as a connector between array and list.

Comment: @alfasin note that `Arrays.asList(...)` returns a `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` which is a private static class, so that code wouldn't work. It should be `List<String> songList ...` anyways.

Comment: @alfasin If you use only Arrays.asList() you won't be able to add new elements, with new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList()) you'll be able to ;) depend what you need

Comment: @alfasin I think `List<String> songList = new ArrayList<String>() {{add("song1");add("song2");} };` would be the one you are trying to say.

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik nope, what I wrote is exactly what I meant. This code doesn't require modifying the list after it was created, just to print its elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("apple");
    list.add("banana");
    Random random = new Random();

    System.out.println(list.get(random.nextInt(list.size())));
```

Comment: I have tried this, but this does not work.

Comment: @ZakiHussain "does not work" is rarely sufficient, you need to specify in what way it doesn't work (e.g. what did you expect and what did you get instead?).

Comment: list.add ... doesn't work. It says illegal start of type

Comment: post your code here. You have to have right type of ArrayList. `List<yourType/Double/Integer/String> ...`

Comment: `ArrayList<String> songList = new ArrayList<>();
    songList.add("song1");
    songList.add("song2");
   
    Random random = new Random();

    System.out.println(list.get(random.nextInt(list.size())));`

Comment: System.out.println(songList.get(random.nextInt(songList.size()))); insteat of  System.out.println(list.get(random.nextInt(list.size())));

Comment: `System.out.println(list.get(random.nextInt(list.size())));` should be
`System.out.println(songList.get(random.nextInt(songList.size())));` just rename the variable. Your code works fine.

Comment: If you don't have any problems, mark this question as the best answer and close this topic. Thanks.